# Mock string resource in Android unit testing using Robolectric 3

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, robolectric

I've read a couple of answers online but none of them seem to work for me.

This is what I have in my `@Setup` method:

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
Configuration mConfiguration = Mockito.mock(Configuration.class);
mConfiguration.locale = Locale.US;
when(mContext.getResources().getConfiguration()).thenReturn(mConfiguration);
when(StorageUtils.getUserAgent(mContext)).thenReturn("User-Agent: Android Unit Test");
when(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.service_domain)).thenReturn("testString");
```

All of it works, except the last line `getString`. Ideally the string would be from the actual strings resource I already have for the whole app, but if that's not possible, I can add it to this line manually.

The part that doesn't work is when I try to call the string.

The `.getString(R.string.service_domain)` part is getting called in another method (the method used in the actual application) as part of the context.

So my method is called like this from unit test:

```
Utils.getProductImageUrl(mContext, product);
```

And this `getProductImageUrl` does this:

```
productImageUrl = context.getString(R.string.service_domain) + baseImageUrl;
```

When I run the unit test, the `productImageUrl` variable get a full url of

```
null/123.png
```

How can I mock the string so it can be passed as part of the context to my method?

Let me know if you need additional information.
Thank you.

Comment: Your code is misleading. You can not mock static things with **Mockito**

Comment: Did you also set deep mooking? Because mock second level dependency is not possible with default configurations

Comment: @EugenMartynov Same thing with RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS flag. getResources().getString() returns null. Even when put "anyInt()" there, so it doesn't depend on generated values of R.string.* constants